# Set line color in component

Tags: android, android-number-picker

How to set NumberPicker horizontal lines to white in layout xml?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom theme for the `NumberPicker`.

Create a `styles.xml` file in `res/values` folder, if it doesn't exist and define a theme for number picker. Define `colorControlNormal` attribute to required color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="NumberPickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item> 
    </style>
</resources>
```

Apply the theme to your NumberPicker.

```
<NumberPicker
        android:theme="@style/NumberPickerTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```